# typecast qgraphicsitem to qgraphicswidget

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicswidget

my qgraphicsscene is having qgraphicswidget which constantly adding qgraphicsLayoutItem. in graphicsView i need to get the qgraphicswidget geometry in scene coordinated. 
i tried 
 QList items = scene()->items();
and check its with type

> foreach (QGraphicsItem *item, items) {
>           if(item->type() == ItemType)
>           {
>           }

but how to convert item to qgraphicswidget and change its gemoetry to scene coordinates. 
normal item.boundingRect returns constantly 0,0, 10x10

Answer (score 1):

The bounding rect of the item is in item coordinates. To map it to scene coordinates, use [QGraphicsItem::mapToScene()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#mapToScene-1):

```
const QRectF mapped = item->mapToScene(item->boundingRect());
```

To cast a QGraphicsItem, you can simply use dynamic_cast or static_cast, or the special [qgraphicsitem_cast](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#qgraphicsitem_cast):

```
auto widget = qgraphicsitem_cast<QGraphicsWidget*>(item);
```

To map the coordinates, casting shouldn’t be necessary though.

Comment: thx for replying Frank. but widget is returning NULL all the time. if(item->type() == jCtnWid)
        {
            auto widget = qgraphicsitem_cast<QGraphicsWidget*>(item);
            if(widget)
            {
                qDebug()<<"The bounding rect:"<<widget->geometry();
            }
        }

Comment: If you’re checking the type anyway, you could just static_cast<>, I guess. How i jCtnWid defined? qgraphicsitem_cast uses type() to check.

Comment: Hi Frank.const int jCtnWid = QGraphicsItem::UserType + 1117; is what i defined. it is returning properly the item as i used the same in mousePress to change the cursor. but in that case im not type casting.